# How to get mouse position over google Marker

Tags: google-maps

I have a map that has several Markers on it.  When zoomed out, these Markers appear to be on top of each other.
I want a menu to popup up on a right click with all of the markers within a certain distance of the mosue when the right mouse button is selected.
The problem is, I can't get the mouse position when it is above a marker.

If I add a "rightclick" listener to the marker

```
        google.maps.event.addListener( marker, "rightclick", function ( e )
        {
            alert( "Lat = " + e.latLng.lat() + ": Lng =" + e.latLng.lng() );
        } );
```

the position in the mouse event is the position of the Marker, not the position of the mouse.

If I add a "rightclick" listener to the map

```
        google.maps.event.addListener( map, "rightclick", function ( e )
        {
            alert( "Lat = " + e.latLng.lat() + ": Lng =" + e.latLng.lng() );
        } );
```

events are not fired when the mouse is above a marker.

Is there any way to get the mouse position when it is above a Marker?

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: what is wrong with using the position of the marker?

Comment: Because the position of the marker is NOT where the user clicked.  The default position of the marker is bottom center.  If the image is 64 pixels, then the mouse is no where near the position of the marker when zoomed in.

Comment: But you are going to be comparing that against the position of other markers aren't you?

Comment: Yes, I am.  I want to compare the position of the mouse with the position of the marker.  If the mouse event uses the position of the marker, that comparison is kind of useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the `clickable`-property of the marker to `false`, then the click-event of the map will fire when you click on a marker.

Comment: I must have misread the API docs, because I thought I saw that clickable defaulted to false.  When explicitly set to false, it appears to do what I want.  Thanks.